# Dapr and using sql statestore instead of redis

Tags: dapr

We would like to test switching from redis to sql statestore component.

From the docs it looks like we can do this with two small modifications:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: statestore
spec:
  type: state.sqlserver  # Switch from redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: connectionString
    value: Server=db;Database=dapr;user id=sa;Password=Your_password123;
  - name: tableName
    value: dapr
```

And in our docker compose file, we added an sql server

```
  db: # added 
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    networks:
      - smi-network
```

I assumed that a new table named dapr would be created in the database dapr. But instead we get the follwing error:

```
level=warning msg="error initializing state store statestore (state.sqlserver/v1): failed to create db schema: Unable to open tcp connection with host 'db:1433': dial tcp 172.29.0.2:1433: connect: connection refused" app_id=daprbackend
```

What have I missed, I assumed since all are on the same network `smi-network` the database would be callable by `db` (if I log into the shell of `db`, I see that the IP address is the same `172.29.0.2` )?

Comment: Suddenly it started working. It might be becouse we swithed to `master` db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/dapr/components-contrib/blob/master/state/sqlserver/migration.go) the database is not created for you. Only the table. So if your connection string includes a database you have to have created it first.

If you don't include a database in your connection string the `master` database will be use and table created there.

I am submitting a pull request now to fix this. If the login you use has permissions the database will be created for you.